# Button Background Not Loading - Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a simple activity that contains a spinner, a listview and a button. I made an xml file for button backgrounds to use, but when I try to put it on a button it doesn't work (not just in this activity, but in any). I tried to put this background on the spinner and it seemed to work, could anyone know why it won't work specifically for buttons?

The xml:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Leaderboard"
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/tvHeadline" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/genreSpinner"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340.5dp"
    android:id="@+id/lvLeaderboard" />

<Button
    android:text="Back to main page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background:"@drawable/button_border"
    android:id="@+id/btnGoBack"
    />
```

how it looks on the design view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP3q0.png

*I can run the app on my phone, but the button backgrounds still won't load

edit: here's the button_border.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:top="8px">
       <layer-list>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#030f0b" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="3px"
                       android:left="3px"
                       android:right="3px"
                       android:top="3px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#051a14" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="2px"
                       android:left="2px"
                       android:right="2px"
                       android:top="2px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#0d4f39" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="2px"
                       android:left="2px"
                       android:right="2px"
                       android:top="2px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#0d4f38" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#0f7556" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#10916f" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#0dba8f" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#05e8b3" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#00ffc8" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#05e8b3" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#0dba8f" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#10916f" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#0f7556" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#0d4f38" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="1px"
                       android:left="1px"
                       android:right="1px"
                       android:top="1px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#0d4f39" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="2px"
                       android:left="2px"
                       android:right="2px"
                       android:top="2px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#051a14" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="2px"
                       android:left="2px"
                       android:right="2px"
                       android:top="2px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#030f0b" />
                   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                   <padding
                       android:bottom="3px"
                       android:left="3px"
                       android:right="3px"
                       android:top="3px" />
               </shape>
           </item>
       </layer-list>
   </item>
   <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
           <corners android:radius="4dp" />
           <padding
               android:bottom="15dp"
               android:left="15dp"
               android:right="15dp"
               android:top="15dp" />
       </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

I should mention that it looks fine on another computer.

Comment: Can you be more clear? i don't understand what is the purpose for the  background button?

Comment: @moumenShobakey it's just to change the button's background, just like sometimes you set the background to be an image.

Comment: android:background="@drawable/button_border" change ":" to "=" !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the general styling (rounded corners etc.) and just change the background color then I use the backgroundTint property

```
android:backgroundTint="@drawable/button_border"
```

Comment: I tried that, but that just changes the background to a solid black.

Comment: @MeowSpaceCat please add your button xml so we could see if there is a problem over there.

Comment: I did, and you can see in the picture that the background works for the spinner (looks like a neon border).

Comment: @MeowSpaceCat doenst mean much, could you please add the xml of the button?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your button_border in your Drawable folder is not correctly set up, or that in your java file you are not calling/setting correctly the spinner.

An example for your button_border could be:

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="@android:color/white">
        </solid>

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/green"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: The thing is, it does work on another computer with the same settings for android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `app:backgroundTint="@null"` and keep `android:background`

```
<Button
    android:text="Back to main page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background:"@drawable/button_border"
    android:id="@+id/btnGoBack"
    app:backgroundTint="@null
    />
```